# spring WebFilter overrides ExceptionHandler header

Tags: java, kotlin, spring-webflux

i'm using both a WebFilter and a WebExceptionHandler.
The WebFilter should add a new header only if the ExceptionHandler didn't set it.
However, the WebFilter is added to the ServerWebExchange before the ExceptionHandler is executed by the WebHttpHandler, so it cannot tell whether the ExceptionHandler was triggered or not.

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
class MyErrorWebExceptionHandler(g: MyErrorAttributes, applicationContext: ApplicationContext, serverCodecConfigurer: ServerCodecConfigurer)
    : AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler(g, ResourceProperties(), applicationContext) {

    init {
        super.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.writers)
        super.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.readers)
    }

    @Override
    override fun getRoutingFunction(errorAttributes: ErrorAttributes): RouterFunction<ServerResponse> {
        return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.all(), HandlerFunction<ServerResponse> { renderErrorResponse(it) })
    }

    private fun renderErrorResponse(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {

        val errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, false)

        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .headers { x ->
                        x.set(c_ApplicationStatus, errorPropertiesMap[c_ApplicationStatus].toString())
                      }.build()
}

@Component
class ServerResponseHeaderWebFilter : WebFilter {
    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        exchange.response.headers.set(c_ApplicationStatus, HttpStatus.OK.value().toString())
        return chain.filter(exchange)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually i found that the header set in the filter can be seen in the request.exchange() object. it must be removed there for the new header set to replace it.

```
private fun renderErrorResponse(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {

        val errorPropertiesMap = getErrorAttributes(request, false)

        request.exchange().response.headers.remove(c_ApplicationStatus)
        return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .headers { x -> x.set(c_ApplicationStatus, value) }
                .build()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can quickly model the execution order in this case, with something like:

```
WebFilter
|- setting the application status header to OK
|- calling chain.filter
   |- finding the handler and calling it
   |- in case of an error, the exception handler is called
|- after chain.filter
```

Once the filter chain is done with the exchange, the response has been committed and processed, so there's no way to change the response headers at that point. With this code sample, the exception handler, if executed, will override whatever header the web filter has set.

So technically, the answer to your question is that there's no way to modify the response once the handler chain has taken care of it. This is the expected behavior of Spring WebFlux, by design.

But it sounds like we need to take a step back and talk about what you're trying to achieve.

Are you trying to check whether your exception handler is being called at all while developing a feature?
Are you trying to adapt the error handling mechanism in Spring Boot in some way that's not possible right now?

If you'd like to talk about what you're trying to achieve, please ask another question so that SO users can benefit from this question.

Comment: well, that flow is what i thought that happens, but actually it doesn't.

Comment: sorry, previous message was cut.
for clarity, let's say my filter sets the header to OK, the error exception handler sets it to ERROR. 
in my tests, whether or not the exception handler is called, i always receive the OK header. 
it looks like the chain.filter(exchange) is applied only after the exception handler is invoked, overriding the header contents.